# Surviving collapsing buildings: Which floor maximizes your chances of survival?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, building-physics

Although this is not a purely physical question, I think this is the best StackExchange place to ask it.

When a building collapses, which floor should you go in order to maximize your chance of survival? In favor of the basement, you could argue, is the fact that your potential energy is minimal there.  Beeing on the top floor, on the other hand, means less mass is falling upon you.

But maybe these aspects are negligible compared to other effects, chaotic ones, even, such as beams from below penetrating the floor, or heavy objects, sliding in unpretictable directions, etc.  Nonetheless, even these chaotic effects may on average lead to better chances on the higher or lower floors.  So tell me, where should I go?

Comment: I think this is off topic because it's not asking about a physical principle. It seems more like a structural engineering question.

Comment: I disagree with @DavidZ; there's plenty of physical principles to consider here. Hope the question remains open.

Comment: @rob note that I didn't say there aren't physical principles involved. Of course there are. The issues is that this question isn't asking about one of them. (If you disagree, then I would ask, what physical principle do you think the question is asking about?)

Answer (score 1):

It is an engineering question because it depends on the building,  a building codes one, if the building collapses because of a bomb, an earthquake or an airplane falling on it as in the towers.

In earthquakes whole apartment buildings end squashed, if the reinforcements in the lower columns are bad. So the roof is safer. In old apartment houses we are advised to go to the staircase, which have a lot of reinforced concrete and often remain standing when the floors  have collapsed. In the latest technology for earthquakes it is the basement because it is all, by law in new buildings in Greece, a box of reinforced concrete that can ride like a boat.